# Indirect function using date as argument returns #REF but typing the date on the formula makes it work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the indirect formula to return a value on a table based on a date (e.g. 31/1/2024). Let's say the table is called table1 and the date is placed on cell E5.

If I use `INDIRECT("table1[" & $E$5 & "]")` it will return `#REF`. However, if I type the date directly on the formula it will work fine: `INDIRECT("table1[" & "31/01/2024" & "]")`. I've used indirect before but never with formulas. Can anyone share some tips to make it work?

Thanks

Edit 1: Using `TEXT` also makes it work, but now makes the excel dependen on locale settings (YYYY in English, AAAA in Spanish, etc.). Any other, more elegant solution? `(INDIRECT("table1[" & TEXT($E$6;"DD/MM/YYYY") & "]")`

Edit 2: To provide an example of my table1: it provides a monthly ratio.

| Date | 31/01/2024 | 29/02/2024 | 31/03/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ratio | 55% | 50% | 53% |

Comment: Using TEXT also makes it work, but now makes the excel dependen on locale  settings (YYYY in English, AAAA in Spanish, etc.). Any other, more elegant solution?

(INDIRECT("table1[" & TEXT($E$6;"DD/MM/YYYY") & "]")

Comment: Enter the date as text.

Comment: Can you post a data example of your table? You are using INDIRECT but maybe you could use INDEX and MATCH to return the whole column based on header. Are your headers stored as dates or as text?

Comment: I've tried using Index Match but the references get overwritten to table notation as soon as my destination range touches the table. Instead of the typical notation I get "=table1[31/01/2023]"

The table is very simple:

Dates:            31/01/2023 28/02/2023 31/03/2023 30/04/2023
Percentage 55% 55% 55% 55%

The headers are stored as dates.

Comment: As pointed out by @Rory, for your formula to work, the value in `E5` **must** be entered as a ***text string***; not as a ***date***. Column Headers in a `Table` are **always** text.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:

- The column headers will be text representations of dates in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`

  - *Note that column headers are **always** text strings*
- Dates (in `E5` for example) will always be entered as ***real*** excel dates and formatted however the user wants.

To deal with this sort of issue, you can use a `Workbook_Open()` macro to properly set up the desired date format string in the appropriate language for the user.

Then use this formula in your worksheet:

```
=INDIRECT("table1[" & TEXT($E$5, dtFmt) & "]")
```

To enter this triggered Macro:

- right click on the sheet tab.
- Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
- If the `Project Explorer` window is not showing, select `View/Project Explorer`
- Navigate to the relevant `VBAProject (your_workbook_name)`
- Double click on `ThisWorkbook`

Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

***Code edited for robustness***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ymd(0 To 2) As String
    
With WorksheetFunction
    ymd(2) = .Rept(Application.International(xlYearCode), 4)    'year code
    ymd(1) = .Rept(Application.International(xlMonthCode), 2)   'month code
    ymd(0) = .Rept(Application.International(xlDayCode), 2)     'day code
End With

'for the first run
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Names("dtFmt").Delete

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="dtFmt", RefersToR1C1:="=" & """" & Join(ymd, "/") & """"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This workaround could wok for you ignoring locale settings but **your headers need to be string dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy**.

[image]

In cell G4 I'm just getting the value of the corresponding date and **always** the first row of data using INDEX and MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Table1;1;MATCH(DAY(G3)&"/"&IF(MONTH(G3)<10;"0"&MONTH(G3);MONTH(G3))&"/"&YEAR(G3);Table1[#Headers];0))
```

Notice the second argument of INDEX is `1` to specify we always want to return the first row of data (intersected with column located using input date). If you leave this argument in blank then **the whole column** will be returned.

In cell G5 is almost the same formula but specifying row number using a second MATCH based on a specific value. This is just in case you need to locate a row. In this example, I want the percentage associated to `31/01/2024` **and** `Ratio3`:

```
=INDEX(Table1;MATCH(F5;Table1[Date];0);MATCH(DAY(G3)&"/"&if(MONTH(G3)<10;"0"&MONTH(G3);MONTH(G3))&"/"&YEAR(G3);Table1[#Headers];0))
```

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're right, actually the formula works because the headers are string representations of dates.

Comment: Exactly.  And is independent of regional settings, as you stated. +1. Using the `TEXT` function also requires string dates. My formula is shorter, but requires VBA and `INDIRECT`